# You can never close the people's mouth

Tags: sentence-request

There is a proverb which says you can never make the people silent and they will make up any story they want about you. Is there such a proverb in AmE?

I have some suggestions here:

> - You can never silence the crowd.
> - Jar’s mouth may be stopped, a man’s cannot.

Do they sound natural to you?

If not, is there any equivalent? If yes, please let me know what is it?

Comment: Are you talking about it in the sense that a ruler cannot silence the populace, or in the sense that people will always gossip and spread rumors?

Comment: If its in the sense that people will always gossip and spread rumours then I think that "haters gonna hate" is quite apt.

Comment: Your examples don't relate to "they will make up any story they want about you" in your explanation.

Comment: @mstorkson I'm about the second choice when you're going to say that people will gossip and spread rumors always

Comment: @MichaelCurry as far as I'm concerned I guess the proverb you cited can be used when you are going give one person a comment about their or someone else's negative comment who always says negative things. But I need to say people "possibly everyone" has the potential of the negative things about you as a typical and you won't be able to prevent them from doing that. Meanwhile does it sound natural in AmE too?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear, I was more joking than anything. I guess it does sound pretty natural in AmE, it was first used by someone famous who was getting a lot of negativity in the media IIRC, and that's why @mstorkson's comment kind of made me think of it.

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate expression I can think of is a '[rumour mill](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rumour-mill)' - an idiomatic expression that relates to the circulation of gossip in a community. For example:

> According to the **rumour mill**, you were seen with John at the party last weekend.
>
> You can't believe everything that comes out of the **rumour mill**.

It can also be used in the context you describe:

> They say you can't stop the **rumour mill** from turning.

...meaning you can't prevent gossip from happening.

Comment: What's you opinion about "haters gonna hate" in AmE @mike? Does it indicate the message in my intention? I'm going to convey this message: " People "possibly everyone" has the potential of the negative things about you as a typical and you won't be able to prevent them from doing that."

Answer (score -3):

I know some idioms about rumours and lies  but I am not sure they fit.

Many a time a man's mouth broke his nose.

Truth ends but the story continues.

"Gossip is just news running ahead of itself in a red satin dress.”-Liz Smith

Lying through his/her teeth.

Loose lips sink ships.

These are better:

[LINK](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/secrets-discretion/secrets1.html)  I really liked "let the cat out of the bag", and "gave the game away"

My favourite was : "It is a secret in the Oxford sense. You may tell it to only one person at a time.

Lord Franks
Lord Franks (1905-1992) English academic, diplomat and philosopher

which is almost the same as "A secret is something you share with one person at a time."

How about, "Gossip runs like a wildfire"?

[I like this article on the subject](http://articles.bplans.com/gossip-of-crowds/)